# Image RotateFlip ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, rotation, flip

This is my fifth day trying to Rotate Image in my Web Application ASP.NET, all the solutions in the internet didn't work with me.

This is my code in .aspx.cs

```C#
protected void BtnRotateImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vImageName = LblFarmId.Text;

        string vPath = "~/attachments/survey/" + vImageName + ".jpg";

        Image1.ImageUrl = vPath;

        //get the path to the image
        string path = Server.MapPath(vPath);

        //create an image object from the image in that path
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);

        //rotate the image
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);

        //save the image out to the file
        img.Save(path);

        //release image file
        img.Dispose();

    }
```

In .aspx page

```html
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl=""  width="600" height="800"/>
```

I click on the button, nothing happen , the image doesn't rotate.

is there any wrong in my code?

Comment: @amdixon can I understand the reason of voting negative? what do you gain from your negative effect? isn't this place to ask questions? what's wrong with you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was you, I'm new here, I read the instruction of the website before I put my question, I always put the question as per the rules of the website, then I find voting down, I started to think that it is not website for asking question, maybe I understood wrong? why some people are so conceited here? I didn't force anyone to answer my question, ignore it if you don't like it, why you put your negative effect? << I mean the one who always do that, is there anything wrong in my question?

Comment: its ok; periodically you will be downvoted, but your question seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button, you are only saving the image. After the image is saved, you need to reload the page with the image tag set to the new path.

Comment: That's correct, I checked now the FTP, the images are rotated, I'm doing now my search to find out how to reload it :D

Comment: Finally I got a solution for refreshing the imageURL 
I would like to write it here, in case someone has the same problem.

I added these two lines at the end of the code.
      
Random rnd = new Random();    
Image1.ImageUrl = vPath + "?" + rnd;
    
Actually ASP doesn't refresh the image when it has the same path/name, so I had to deludes it that the path has been changed while it doesn't effect viewing the same image , the number after ? doesn't effect the path of the correct image, it tried to use datetime so it can't repeated but give error "not a valid virtual path"

Comment: ? is an illegal char in windows filenames. And to make rotation iterative without long filenames add an integer counter to file name using code like `private string getNextFileName(string fileName)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

    int i = 0;
    while (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        if (i == 0)
            fileName = fileName.Replace(extension, "(" + ++i + ")" + extension);
        else
            fileName = fileName.Replace("(" + i + ")" + extension, "(" + ++i + ")" + extension);
    }

    return fileName;`
}